# PHP static class return reference

Tags: php, object, reference, static

I have class with a static method. The static method returns a private static stdClass object.

```
myclass::get() // returns stdClass object
myclass::get()->name // name is hardcoded into the class
```

How would I change name's value like:

```
myclass::get()->name = 'bob';
```

and have it set?

I tried returning the object like:

```
return &self::$static_object;
```

But that throws syntax errors.

What can i do?

EDIT posted code for clarification

```
final class config {

    private static $configs = array();

    public static function get($config_name) {

        if (isset($configs[$config_name])) {

            return self::$configs[$config_name];
        }

        $file = __get_file_exists(M_CONFIGS . $config_name, 'conf.');

        if ($file) {

            $config = self::__scope_include($file);

            if (!is_array($config) && !$config instanceof stdClass) {
                /*
                 * 
                 * 
                 * FIX
                 * 
                 * 
                 * 
                 */
                die('ERROR config.php');
            }

            return self::$configs[$config_name] = self::__to_object($config);
        }
    }

    private static function __scope_include($file) {

        return include $file;
    }

    private static function __to_object($config) {

        $config = (object) $config;

        foreach ($config as &$value) {

            if (is_array($value)) {

                $value = self::__to_object($value);
            }
        }

        return $config;
    }
}

echo config::get('people')->name; //dave
config::get('people')->name = 'bob';
echo config::get('people')->name; // should be bob, is dave
```

Comment: What do you mean by *name is hardcoded into the class*? If short enough, post the `get` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `self` in `if (isset($configs[$config_name])) {`. It should be

```
if (isset(self::$configs[$config_name])) {
  return self::$configs[$config_name];
}
```

Otherwise each time you call `config::get('people')`, you will be reading your config file which most likely returns an array and convert it to an object before returning it. Any changes you make to the object in `self::$configs[$config_name]` are overwritten by the newly created object.

Comment: Thank you ! I new it had to be something simple, can't believe I missed that haha :)

Answer (score 5):

Returning by reference in the `get()` method should do the trick:

```
public static function &get() {
    return self::$static_object;
}
```

But, I think you should revisit your design, as this kind of coding is highly frowned upon and will cause maintenance and testability headaches down the road.

Comment: I don't believe in down votes, but your answer [smells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: Please actually read my answer next time before commenting.  I quite clearly advise against using this kind of code.

Comment: You still provided code to the contrary. :) Take the time and show the *better* way to do it.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: I believe in answering questions directly, and providing disclaimers where applicable.  This is the only way for people to learn more about how PHP works.  Answers like yours, while they advocate best practices, don't do anything to teach people about the nuances of the language.  Different strokes for different folks, I guess.

Comment: I understand. But I worry that philosophy - PHP *allows* it so it's *okay* - leads to why PHP devs get a bad rep. As a PHP developer, I want to [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: There's nothing inherently wrong with returning things by reference.  PHP allows you to do that, and it **is** okay.  It's the _application_ of this feature that may or may not be good practice.  In this case, it would be bad practice, and I noted that.  But if you completely glaze over the feature itself in order to promote good practice, then people reading it may never learn about the actual feature, and when they come across a valid use-case for it in the future, they won't have that tool in their tool-belt.  At least, that's my $0.02, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing and the answer from **drrcknlsn** break [*Encapsulation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). That is bad.

The correct way to do this is to create a *setter* method.

```
public static function set($key, $value) {
  // set $config property...
}
```